# WP Installer Redirects to /wp-admin/core/install.php

Tags: installation

I am trying to install WP for the first time on Ubuntu 12.04 in a clean /var/www directory. I downloaded the latest version. I untarred it in my home directory and then moved it to /var/www.  I created the DB and edited the wp-config.php file.

When I visit the base URL (an IP address for now), the URL gets rewritten as xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/wp-admin/core/install.php.  But, there is no core directory.

What is happening here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I was trying to install WordPress on VM configured on my laptop. The VM IP was `192.168.1.101` and the database host configured in wp-config.php was 'localhost' but I changed that to the actual IP and added privileges in MySQL to access the database from said IP.